# Incorrect syntax near '(' when updating record in database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My code is producing an `Incorrect syntax near '('` exception. I have tried two different ways but they both produce the same exception. I am trying to update a record in the database.

Here is my code and the line that produces the exception is the Execute non query line. The `updater.Fill(dtable)` which is commented out also produces the same exception.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int found = 0; // No match found so far

    // Get the current selected Manufacturer
    string currentManufacturer = grdManufact.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    string currentIsModerated = grdManufact.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;

    // Connect to the database
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString); 
    conn.Open();


    // Try to find if new record would be a duplicate of an existing database record
    if (txtManufactureName.Text != currentManufacturer)
    {
        string findrecord = "SELECT * From VehicleManufacturer WHERE ManufacturerName = '" + txtManufactureName.Text + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(findrecord, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        found = adpt.Fill(dt);
    }

    if (found == 0) // New record is not a duplicate you can proceed with record update
    {
        String query;
        if (checkBoxModerated.Checked)
        {
            query = "UPDATE VehicleManufacturer (ManufacturerName, ManufacturerDescription, Ismoderated) Values ('" + txtManufactureName.Text + "','" + txtDescription.Text + "','true') WHERE ManufacturerName = " + currentManufacturer + ";";
        }
        else
        {
            query = "UPDATE VehicleManufacturer (ManufacturerName, ManufacturerDescription, Ismoderated) Values ('" + txtManufactureName.Text + "','" + txtDescription.Text + "','false') WHERE ManufacturerName = " + currentManufacturer + ";";
        }
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
       //using (SqlDataAdapter updater = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
       // {
        //    DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        //    updater.Fill(dtable);
       // }
        txtMessage.Text = "Manufacturer record changed Successfully";
        txtManufactureName.Text = "";
        txtDescription.Text = "";
        checkBoxModerated.Checked = false;

    }
    else
    { // Record is a duplicate of existing database records. Give error message.
        txtMessage.Text = "Sorry, that manufacturer name already exists.";
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL UPDATE Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: I think you'll find it's actually the update query that's causing the exception, not the `ExecuteNonQuery()`. Check the SQL syntax for updating then try again.

Comment: This code is ripe for sql injection. You should sanitize your inputs.

Comment: Please don't recommend a method that goes against all security best practices. Using dynamic sql is fine but please parameterize the inputs.

Comment: How do I sanitize my inputs? I just want this fixed first I will think about sanitizing my inputs later.

Comment: I changed the query to this :

Comment: query = "UPDATE VehicleManufacturer SET ManufacturerName ='" + txtManufactureName.Text + "', ManufacturerDescription ='" + txtDescription.Text + "', IsModerated = 'false') WHERE ManufacturerName = '" + currentManufacturer + "';";

Comment: Still producing same exception

Comment: This bad, bad bad bad bad...plese don't use inline SQL IN this way:(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the incorrect syntax for UPDATE statements.

Instead of

```
UPDATE Table (Fields) VALUES (Values) WHERE ...
```

It should be

```
UPDATE Table SET Field1=Value1, Field2=Value2 WHERE ...
```

Additionally, you have a SQL injection vulnerability (although this is not the reason for your exception).
Do not use string concatenation for SQL queries with user input. Use [prepared statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Tried doing your way with the following statement :

Comment: query = "UPDATE VehicleManufacturer SET ManufacturerName ='" + txtManufactureName.Text + "', ManufacturerDescription ='" + txtDescription.Text + "', IsModerated = 'false') WHERE ManufacturerName = '" + currentManufacturer + "';";

Comment: Still produces same exception! :(

Comment: @SolimanSamirSoliman You sure the new exception doesn't mention `)` instead of `(`? Because you still have an extra `)` before `WHERE`. Also, your modified code is still vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: Thank you Luis Cubal. You have worked out the problem. How can I reward you?

Comment: query = "UPDATE VehicleManufacturer SET ManufacturerName ='" + txtManufactureName.Text + "', ManufacturerDescription ='" + txtDescription.Text + "', IsModerated = 'true') WHERE ManufacturerName = '" + currentManufacturer + "';"; Should be query = "UPDATE VehicleManufacturer SET ManufacturerName ='" + txtManufactureName.Text + "', ManufacturerDescription ='" + txtDescription.Text + "', IsModerated = 'true' WHERE ManufacturerName = '" + currentManufacturer + "';"; That means there is an extra ')' before WHERE. It works like a dream now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach , it's safer also:

```
var isModerated = checkBoxModerated.Checked ; //true or false
//var isModerated = (checkBoxModerated.Checked)? 'true' : 'false' ;

command.Text = "UPDATE VehicleManufacturer 
                SET ManufacturerName = @manufacturerName, 
                    ManufacturerDescription = @manufacturerDescription, 
                    IsModerated = @isModerated  
                WHERE ManufacturerName = @manufacturer_name";



command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manufacturerName", txtManufactureName.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manufacturerDescription", txtDescription.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isModerated", isModerated);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manufacturer_name", txtManufactureName.Text);


command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This way gives me a incorrect syntax near WHERE. I went with the answer above. It was an extra '(' before the WHERE. Silly syntax error.

Comment: @SolimanSamirSoliman sorry I had an extra comma there, fixed it now